# Using Emotion CSS-in-JS with theming in React

Tags: reactjs, theming, styled-components, emotion

First off, I'm fairly new to React, so I'm still learning my way around.

I'm following the [Introduction Article (Medium.com)](https://medium.com/@tkh44/emotion-ad1c45c6d28b) on setting up using [Themes](https://github.com/iamstarkov/theming) with [Emotion](https://github.com/tkh44/emotion). But I'm stuck with trying to use a theme color in a const that will be used within a `compose`

For instance, I have:

```
const types = {
  primary: (props) => css`color: ${props.theme.blue}`,
  secondary: (props) => css`color: ${props.theme.red}`
};

const Button = withTheme(styled.button`
  composes: ${props => types[props.type]};
`);
```

(This is a contrived example. In reality, my `primary` and `secondary` will have a lot more CSS.)

If I render `<Button type="primary">A Button</Button>`, the color doesn't get applied. In fact, if I inspect the element, I don't even see a `color` style.

However, if instead I change `Button` to:

```
const Button = withTheme(styled.button`
  composes: ${types.primary};
`);
```

Then I see the correct color being applied.

I'm not totally sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just a little background:

[Tagged template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Tagged_template_literals) of ES2015 are template literals that can be parsed by a function by 'tagging' it with one (such as `styled.button`). That function receives the template literal and all `${}` placeholders and returns the resulting string. `${}` can contain anything considered a javascript expression, e.g. a single value, function, etc.

In the case of `styled` from emotion, if you pass a function into any of the placeholders, it will call that function, passing in the props of the `styled` element you have used (in your example a `button`) as the first argument. If you wrap the `styled` template literal with a `withTheme` call, that `props` argument object will contain the theme prop you originally provided to the `<ThemeProvider>` at your app's base component.

In your example, the reason it works for the second code block is because you are passing a function that will return a value. In the first code block you as passing a function that when called will return another function. This means the resulting style will contain a function, rather than a value.

```
const types = {
  primary: (props) => css`color: ${props.theme.blue}`,
  secondary: (props) => css`color: ${props.theme.red}`
};

const Button = withTheme(styled.button`
  composes: ${props => types[props.type]};
`);
```

In the case of 'primary' the above evaluates to:

```
const Button = withTheme(styled.button`
  composes: ${props => (props) => css`color: ${props.theme.blue}`};
`);
```

As you can see that is one level too deep. The theme will get passed in as part of `props` but the second deeper function would need to be called for the `css` function to then be called. In the second code block, 'primary' would evaluate to:

```
const Button = withTheme(styled.button`
  composes: ${(props) => css`color: ${props.theme.blue}`};
`);
```

This would give the correct result as `styled.button` will pass the props in and `css` uses them within the called function directly.

Hopefully this makes some sense. This is my first stack overflow answer attempt so I am happy to improve it if it can be.